# C# Button.image

Tags: c#, image, button, background

I've been on this for a while but can't get it to work.
I came from C# programming within Unity3D, but now need to build something in "normal" C# now through Visual Studio.

So I've got this button in C#, which I want to give a background. No biggy.
But the problem is, I want the background to expand itself.
So I want an image like this: !http://i39.tinypic.com/2wphvo6.png combined with a button so it becomes like this: !http://i42.tinypic.com/dzxlom.jpg

In Unity3D it was easy, but I don't know how to get it to work in Visual Studio C#. Hope someone can help me. I don't even know how to properly call this image expanding to button thing...

edit: Windows Forms

Comment: It would help if you tell us whether by "normal" you mean WPF or Windows Forms, because the answer will be quite different.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I meant for Windows Forms :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the change the picture on mouse over you can do something like this using events

```
    public Form1()
                  {
                       InitializeComponent();
                       button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
                       button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
                  }

                  void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
                  {
                       this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
                       this.button1.Size = button1.BackgroundImage.Size;
                  }


                  void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
                  {
                       this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
                       this.button1.Size = button1.BackgroundImage.Size;
                  }
```

Comment: For me that's just filling the buttons with those images. As in, it gets  tiled.

I'm doing this: 
Image im = Image.FromFile(@"C:\ProjectSilver\assets\RadarDetectie\register\btn_blue_normal.png");
buttonArray[i].BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(im));


I don´t want to adjust the button to the image, I want the image to adjust to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch; //Or maybe you want Zoom
}
```

You can also set the property in the design view of the form.